# what is the difference between brew service install hbase and download the src/bin file from the official website?

Tags: hbase, homebrew

I have gone through a lot of tutorials regarding how to set up hbase on mac. Some do it with brew install and others download it from the website, I am confused of the difference between these two.

Similarly, one can start hbase by doing `brew services start hbase` or `run start-hbase.sh` in dir `/usr/local/Cellar/hbase/x.x.x`, is there a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much the same (in the sense of the results), but homebrew services is a daemon service manager, which means would also automatically start the service(s) after the computer started.

This is [homebrew services repo](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-services), which got shipped besides homebrew core functionality.